# Using FME for adding history to object?

Tags: fme-form

I have a very specific problem and I'm looking for a solution for it.
I need to add some sort of history to an object. The history will be stored like this:

- begin_date
- end_date
- previous_id

Suppose the object that I'm wanting to add the history to is X. We have a central database (at the moment all mdb files, we will switch soon to gdb though) that contains the object X with the history. Workers on the field have a local version of the database and they also fill an object X_i that has an attribute changed.
X and X_i have an id to track them.

Now when we want to merge the local version of the database a script should run and fill the history of the central db like this:

```
if X_i.changed = true:
    search central_X.id, fill end_date with today
    search local_X.id, copy this attribute to central_X and:
        fill begin_date
        fill previous_id with central_X.id
        generate new unique id for the central_X
```

We also add new fields to the central db and update the unique ids:

```
for every i in local_X:
    if i not in central_X:
        copy i to central_X
        generate new unique id for i
        enter begin_date
```

For deleted items we do something similar but then we set the end_date.

At the end of the merge. We create a new X_i where all the ids are correctly filled and the changed attribute is empty everywhere.

What FME functions could be used for this?

I have looked at alternatives like an ArcSDE with archiving, but that would mean we would need to invest in an ArcSDE, change a significant part of our workflow and not all items that we change will have X_i.changed, so the archiving would contain way too much information to be really useful.

---

Added workflow to clarify.
[image: workflow]

1. I can use changedetector for this.
2. If X_i.changed is true
3. If X_i.id is not empty
4. set end_date for all processed data
5. **no idea how to do this**
6. **no idea how to do this**
7. **no idea how to do this**
8. find the biggest id so far and proceed from this id.

Comment: 5. use ListBuilder 6. AttributeCopier 7. FeatureMerger

Answer (score 4):

FME with the TimeStamper
http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/TimeStamper

Use your previous_id and define the begin date

any changes to the data can be recorded with previous_id changes and current_id where the timestamper can be assigned and end_date.

Python can be used to record historic changes
http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Update after comment

[image]

http://docs.safe.com/fme/2009/html/Transformers/content/transformers/changedetector.htm

Comment: My problem is not really adding the time to the data, but how can I compare the 2 datasets and find out what has changed.

Comment: Then you need ChangeDetector http://docs.safe.com/fme/2009/html/Transformers/content/transformers/changedetector.htm added image to previous answer.

Comment: I updated my description with a workflow to show what steps I don't know how to do at the moment. So your changedetector helps, but I'm not there yet.